# Where to call an Ajax Request that would Happen before Render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that has a dropdown of categories and once a user chooses a choice from the dropdown they go to another page.

However sometimes there is only 1 category and I want to skip the dropdown selection and go right to the second page.

However I am getting the categories by an ajax call so I don't know how many catgories are coming back till the ComponentDidMount happens.

If there is only 1 choice I then do a route change(in the ComponentDidMount ) and send them to the second page automatically.

However this leads to a flicker on the ui(first tries to render the first page but once it mounts the code to go to the next page gets hit).

Is there another area I can do this kind of check?

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps()? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Yea I was thinking of using this but was not sure if this was good practice to do any ajax call like this in there.

Answer (score 0):

How about just showing a loader while result is being fetched from server. That way user wouldn't see any flicker on screen.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetchCategories().then((categories) => {
     if (categories.length === 1) {
       // Redirect
     }
     else {
       this.setState({ categories })
     }
  })
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.categories) {
      // Show loader while categories are being fetched.
      return <Loader />
  }
  else if(this.state.categories.length > 1) {
     // Show content if categories are more
     return <Categories />
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, loader was an option I was thinking around but I felt that there might be a flicker of the loader as it does not take long to get the categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loading state/indicator before rendering/re-routing.
When the ajax call is complete set the loaded state/prop after which either the dropdown will be rendered or page re-routed without a flicker.

Sample without redux/global state management

```
//****************************************************************************/

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
        categoriesLoaded: false
    }
}

//****************************************************************************/

componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchCategories().then(response => {

        this.setState({ categoriesLoaded: true })

    }).catch(e => {

        ...handle
    })
}

//****************************************************************************/

render() {

    return (
        {this.state.categoriesLoaded && (

            handle list display or reroute
        )}
    )
}
```